# How to show two different FlatList on one page in react native

Tags: reactjs, list, react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

I have to show two different FlatList one has only single column and another has  two columns on same screen and I want to show it in a manner once first list data has completed only then it will show the next list at the bottom of that.

I have tried but first list is capturing half screen and second is capturing the another half. I want to resolve that.

Image reference for layout : https://prnt.sc/z1lEI29sYqhN

List 1:

```
 <FlatList
    data={topics}
    renderItem={({item, index}) => (
 )}
    numColumns={1}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    contentContainerStyle={{marginTop: height * 0.01, height: 'auto', flex: 0 }}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  />
```

List 2:

```
<FlatList
    data={topics}
    renderItem={({item, index}) => (
 )}
    numColumns={2}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    contentContainerStyle={{marginTop: height * 0.01, height: 'auto', flex: 0 }}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

MarginTop is not a good way to do this, [CSS Tricks - flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
    <FlatList1 style={{flex:8}} />
    <FlatList2 style={{flex:2}} />
</View>
```

This should do the trick if I understood your problem correctly

Comment: Thankyou but I need to have flex based on the items in list. The first can have one item or 2 or nothing